# How Semiparametric regression works?

Tags: regression, nonparametric, nonparametric-regression, semiparametric

I am working on semiparametric regression models;
$$y=\beta x_1 +m(x_2)+e$$. I can understand this combination of Parametric and Nonparametric but how to estimate the responses ($\hat y$)?

What is algorithm of SPR? How to calculate MSE?

**Edited**

Steps:

- Use Robinson estimator to estimate $\beta$, suppose $\hat \beta=0.4$
- use Kernels for nonparametric Part and calculate estimated $y$ by regressing $y-\beta x_1$ on $x_2$
- - MSE= $y-0.4*x_1-\hat y$
    Is this right?

Comment: There are many algorithms. Backfitting, and splines are common ways to fit additively separable models. But it's a general concept that can be adapted in various ways.

Comment: Suppose I want to use Kernels 4 NP part. Then....???

Comment: @generic_user kindly see my edit.

Comment: You know what the Robinson estimator is but you don't know how to calculate MSE???

Comment: Help Tutorials have till this estimator to estimate beta but how deal with this after estimating beta?

Comment: @generic_user my steps are right or wrong? Please correct them if wrong